# How to call a JavaScript function in the HTTP response?

Tags: java, javascript, webserver

I'm implementing a web server. I have a chat application on it. When I publish a new message, an HTTP request is generated, it calls the right method in the server (Java), and get a response from the server, includes in its content the new HTML code of the chat page.

I don't want to refresh the whole page, so I want to call a JavaScript function that will inject the new message to the right div.

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Tomer

Comment: Well, how do you "publish" if not by calling an XHR function from inside JavaScript?

Comment: I send my server the message, and the server returns a response that includes the page's HTML code with the new message in it (it wraps the message with HTML tags and concatenates it to the current code). I want the server to call a JavaScript function in the page that will inject the message to the right place without a "hard refresh".

Comment: You are looking for Ajax. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better/simpler to use something like jQuery's ajax [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).